# Reverse One-to-Many-Relationship in Django

Tags: django-models

My app links invoices, contracts and services with Many-to-One-Relationships:

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    contract = models.ForeignKey(Contract, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Contract(models.Model):
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Whenever a new invoice is registered, it can be linked to a service and split/billed internally. Unfortunately, some contracts/invoices need to be linked to more than one service according to a fixed split (e.g. 30/70).

For this to work on the surface, I could to reverse the relationship between contracts and services –

```
class Service(models.Model):
    contract = models.ForeignKey(Contract, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

– or change the `ForeignKey` field on the `Contract` class to a `ManyToManyField`.

But in both cases, I will not be able to get back from the invoice to the service easily anymore, as with the following statement:

```
invoices = Invoice.objects.filter(models.Q(contract__service__building=self.tenant.unit.building), models.Q(begin__lte=self.begin, end__gt=self.begin) | models.Q(begin__gt=self.begin, begin__lt=self.end))
```

Is it wise to insert an intermediate helper model (`ContractService`) with two `ForeignKey` fields to keep the current app logic and add the option to link a contract to more than one service?

Comment: Lets try in english, without code: One Invoice can be linked to multiple Services. One Service can "hold" multiple Invoices. But how do you want to fit in the Contract?

Comment: I created these relations because they felt natural: For each service, there is one contract (at a time), and invoices are related to a contract directly. But you're right: I could link services and invoices in a ManyToMany relationship, and just link a contract to each invoice with a separate ForeignKey..

Answer (score 0):

Ok just to clarify one example:

- Contract is "Cleaning of House"
- Services are "Cleaning of first floor" and "Cleaning of second floor"
- Invoices are "Invoice1", "Invoice2", ...

You want a relationship that "Invoice1" can be linked to "Cleaning of first floor" AND "Cleaning of second floor".

models.py

```py
class Contract(models.Model):
    """Can hold multiple Services"""
    pass

class Service(models.Model):
    """Is linked to one specific Contract"""
    contract = models.ForeignKey(Contract, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Invoice(models.Model):
    """Can hold multiple Services and one Service can hold multiple Invoices"""
    service = models.ManyToManyField(Service)
```

Now your question is:
"I can easily get the contract when I have the Service object, but how can I get the Service when I have the Contract object?

```py
con = Contract.objects.all().first()
queryset = con.service_set.all()  # gives you all related Services for that specific Contract
```

Read more about [ManytoOne](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)

And:
"How can I get the Invoice when I have the Service object?"

```py
ser = Service.objects.all().first()
queryset = ser.invoice_set.all() # gives you all related Invoices for that specific Service
```

Read more about [ManyToMany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Let me know how it goes

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Tarquinius for your help – I found a solution based on his suggestion. The three models in question are connected as follows:

```
class Service(models.Model):
    pass

class Contract(models.Model):
    services = models.ManyToManyField(Service)

class Invoice(models.Model):
    contract = models.ForeignKey(Contract, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The query quoted above did not even need to be modified (apart from the different fieldname) to reflect the possibility of more than one service per contract, I just had to add the distinct() function:

```
invoices = Invoice.objects.filter(models.Q(contract__services__building=self.tenancy_agreement.unit.building), models.Q(begin__lte=self.begin, end__gt=self.begin) | models.Q(begin__gt=self.begin, begin__lt=self.end)).distinct()
```

In hindsight, this is quite obvious (and simple).